# ASP Report Viewer 11 Rendering issue

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I'm trying to display a couple of our SSRS reports in an ASP webapp we'll use internally, I opted to go with local reports over remote, recreated one of them and put together a quick ASP forms site from the VS2012 template and a page with a report viewer control, the report seems to be rendering with a lot of extra space between the various gauges and graphs, below if a link to pictures of the report in report designer and report viewer in FireFox(it renders this way in Chrome and IE10 too), as you can see the amount of extra space isn't the same across all of the objects, and moving the gauge panels in the report to have less or more space between them has no affect, I tried it with a panel half way overlapping another and it displayed the same way in report viewer.

I've tried just about everything I can think of so wondering if anyone else has any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

https://picasaweb.google.com/110986692033703031755/ReportViewer?authuser=0&feat=directlink

Here's the Report Viewer config:

```
<asp:Content ID="LineReportViewer" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer_Line_Overview" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Height="768px" Width="1280px" ShowToolBar="False" SizeToReportContent="True"  ShowWaitControlCancelLink="False">
        <LocalReport ReportPath="Reports\Line_Overview.rdlc" EnableExternalImages="True" EnableHyperlinks="True">
            <DataSources>
                <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="Production_Data" Name="OEEView" />                </DataSources>
        </LocalReport>
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In page inspector I was able to find a couple of empty table sections what were being placed next to two of the gauges and one of the graphs, I have no idea why they were there but I deleted and recreated the affected report parts and everything looks good now.